# Create for every object in a json file a div in htl

Tags: javascript, html, json

I've got a json file like that:

```
{
  "text": "HelloWorld",
  "id": "1",
},
{
  "text": "HelloMoon",
  "id": "2",
}
```

And now I want to create for every object a div in my html. In the div, I want to have two `<p>` tags where I want to show the *text* and the *id*. What do I have to do?

Comment: _"What do I have to do?"_ - First step would be to fix the invalid _"json file"_ + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You can use http://json-validator.com/ to fix your JSON

Comment: And when you've got your JSON into fit, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your idea right you need fix a little styling of your json and then iterate through your objects and append nodes to the root element.

I maid a small demo for you.

```js
const myObjects = [
        {
            "text": "HelloWorld",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "text": "HelloMoon",
            "id": "2"
        }
    ];

    const app = document.getElementById("root");
    myObjects.forEach((obj) => {
        const node = document.createElement("P");                // Create a <p> node
        const textNode = document.createTextNode(obj.text);      // Create a text node
        node.appendChild(textNode);                              // Append the text to your <p> node
        node.setAttribute("id", obj.id);                         // Create an id

        app.appendChild(node);                                  // Append node that you created to the root <div>
    });
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: (There is no JSON in the answer)